# Apple Speech API - SFTranscriptionSegment's have same confidence value

Tags: ios, iphone, ios11

I've noticed a strange behaviour using the Apple Speech Framework.

After implementing in my own app and playing with the examples provided by Apple and online, I've noticed that the speech framework always returns the same confidence level for each transcription's segments following the results of a speech detection.

Here is formatted data from a test I performed with the raw dump at the bottom of this Q, you'll notice that for each SFTranscription, the segments by index have the same confidence value, despite being different objects with different transcriptions.

I'm assuming this is incorrect as it's says in the documentation that the results are ordered by confidence, with the most confident first.

If anyone know's of a fix for this or can point me to somewhere explicitly acknowledging that there is an issue, it would be most helpful.

`[
<SFTranscription: 0x1c0032320>, formattedString=Hey there what's going on with you today how are you looking for things are you alright, 
segments=(
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275340> confidence=0.931,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275000> confidence=0.928,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0270e00> confidence=0.928,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275dc0> confidence=0.924,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275040> confidence=0.925,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275300> confidence=0.925,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275b00> confidence=0.925,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c026db80> confidence=0.925,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c026dbc0> confidence=0.925,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0271380> confidence=0.927,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c026d9c0> confidence=0.818349,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c026db00> confidence=0.942,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0271b00> confidence=0.826,
), 
<SFTranscription: 0x1c002fba0>, formattedString=Hello what's going on with you today how are you looking for things are you alright, 
segments=(
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c026dc80> confidence=0.6732572, 
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c02752c0> confidence=0.931,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275600> confidence=0.928,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0276b80> confidence=0.924,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c00760c0> confidence=0.925,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0075c40> confidence=0.925,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0075e00> confidence=0.925,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c00719c0> confidence=0.925,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0075740> confidence=0.925, 
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0076f00> confidence=0.927,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0276980> confidence=0.818349,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0279200> confidence=0.942
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c027bcc0> confidence=0.826,
), 
<SFTranscription: 0x1c0030c00>, formattedString=Hey there what's going on with you today how are you looking for things that you alright,
segments=(
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275340> confidence=0.6732572, 
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c027bd00> confidence=0.931,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275000> confidence=0.928,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0270e00> confidence=0.928, 
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275dc0> confidence=0.924,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275040> confidence=0.925,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275300> confidence=0.925,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275b00> confidence=0.925,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c026db80> confidence=0.925,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c026dbc0> confidence=0.925,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0271380> confidence=0.927,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c027bc80> confidence=0.818349,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c027bd40> confidence=0.942,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c027bd80> confidence=0.826,
),
<SFTranscription: 0x1c0033860>, formattedString=Hey there what's going on with you today how are you looking for things are you are right, segments=(
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275340> confidence=0.6732572,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c027bd00> confidence=0.931,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275000> confidence=0.928,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0270e00> confidence=0.928,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275dc0> confidence=0.924,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275040> confidence=0.925,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275300> confidence=0.925,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275b00> confidence=0.925,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c026db80> confidence=0.925,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c026dbc0> confidence=0.925,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0271380> confidence=0.927,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c026d9c0> confidence=0.818349,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c026db00> confidence=0.942,
    <SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c027bdc0> confidence=0.826,
)]`

`[<SFTranscription: 0x1c0032320>, formattedString=Hey there what's going on with you today how are you looking for things are you alright, segments=(
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275340>, substringRange={0, 16}, timestamp=0.28, duration=0.52, confidence=0.6732572, substring=Hey there what's, alternativeSubstrings=(\n    \"Hello what's\"\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c027bd00>, substringRange={17, 5}, timestamp=0.8, duration=0.26, confidence=0.931, substring=going, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275000>, substringRange={23, 2}, timestamp=1.06, duration=0.09999999999999987, confidence=0.928, substring=on, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0270e00>, substringRange={26, 4}, timestamp=1.16, duration=0.1500000000000001, confidence=0.928, substring=with, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275dc0>, substringRange={31, 3}, timestamp=1.31, duration=0.1099999999999999, confidence=0.924, substring=you, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275040>, substringRange={35, 5}, timestamp=1.42, duration=0.3200000000000001, confidence=0.925, substring=today, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275300>, substringRange={41, 3}, timestamp=1.74, duration=0.1600000000000001, confidence=0.925, substring=how, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275b00>, substringRange={45, 3}, timestamp=1.9, duration=0.1100000000000001, confidence=0.925, substring=are, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c026db80>, substringRange={49, 3}, timestamp=2.01, duration=0.1699999999999999, confidence=0.925, substring=you, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c026dbc0>, substringRange={53, 7}, timestamp=2.18, duration=0.3300000000000001, confidence=0.925, substring=looking, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0271380>, substringRange={61, 3}, timestamp=2.51, duration=0.1199999999999997, confidence=0.927, substring=for, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c026d9c0>, substringRange={65, 10}, timestamp=2.63, duration=0.3800000000000003, confidence=0.818349, substring=things are, alternativeSubstrings=(\n    \"things that\"\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c026db00>, substringRange={76, 3}, timestamp=3.01, duration=0.1499999999999999, confidence=0.942, substring=you, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0271b00>, substringRange={80, 7}, timestamp=3.16, duration=1.62, confidence=0.826, substring=alright, alternativeSubstrings=(\n    \"are right\"\n)"
), <SFTranscription: 0x1c002fba0>, formattedString=Hello what's going on with you today how are you looking for things are you alright, segments=(
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c026dc80>, substringRange={0, 12}, timestamp=0.28, duration=0.52, confidence=0.6732572, substring=Hello what's, alternativeSubstrings=(\n    \"Hey there what's\"\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c02752c0>, substringRange={13, 5}, timestamp=0.8, duration=0.26, confidence=0.931, substring=going, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0273500>, substringRange={19, 2}, timestamp=1.06, duration=0.09999999999999987, confidence=0.928, substring=on, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275600>, substringRange={22, 4}, timestamp=1.16, duration=0.1500000000000001, confidence=0.928, substring=with, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0276b80>, substringRange={27, 3}, timestamp=1.31, duration=0.1099999999999999, confidence=0.924, substring=you, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c00760c0>, substringRange={31, 5}, timestamp=1.42, duration=0.3200000000000001, confidence=0.925, substring=today, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0075c40>, substringRange={37, 3}, timestamp=1.74, duration=0.1600000000000001, confidence=0.925, substring=how, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0075e00>, substringRange={41, 3}, timestamp=1.9, duration=0.1100000000000001, confidence=0.925, substring=are, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c00719c0>, substringRange={45, 3}, timestamp=2.01, duration=0.1699999999999999, confidence=0.925, substring=you, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0075740>, substringRange={49, 7}, timestamp=2.18, duration=0.3300000000000001, confidence=0.925, substring=looking, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0076f00>, substringRange={57, 3}, timestamp=2.51, duration=0.1199999999999997, confidence=0.927, substring=for, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0276980>, substringRange={61, 10}, timestamp=2.63, duration=0.3800000000000003, confidence=0.818349, substring=things are, alternativeSubstrings=(\n    \"things that\"\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0279200>, substringRange={72, 3}, timestamp=3.01, duration=0.1499999999999999, confidence=0.942, substring=you, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c027bcc0>, substringRange={76, 7}, timestamp=3.16, duration=1.62, confidence=0.826, substring=alright, alternativeSubstrings=(\n    \"are right\"\n)"
), <SFTranscription: 0x1c0030c00>, formattedString=Hey there what's going on with you today how are you looking for things that you alright, segments=(
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275340>, substringRange={0, 16}, timestamp=0.28, duration=0.52, confidence=0.6732572, substring=Hey there what's, alternativeSubstrings=(\n    \"Hello what's\"\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c027bd00>, substringRange={17, 5}, timestamp=0.8, duration=0.26, confidence=0.931, substring=going, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275000>, substringRange={23, 2}, timestamp=1.06, duration=0.09999999999999987, confidence=0.928, substring=on, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0270e00>, substringRange={26, 4}, timestamp=1.16, duration=0.1500000000000001, confidence=0.928, substring=with, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275dc0>, substringRange={31, 3}, timestamp=1.31, duration=0.1099999999999999, confidence=0.924, substring=you, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275040>, substringRange={35, 5}, timestamp=1.42, duration=0.3200000000000001, confidence=0.925, substring=today, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275300>, substringRange={41, 3}, timestamp=1.74, duration=0.1600000000000001, confidence=0.925, substring=how, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275b00>, substringRange={45, 3}, timestamp=1.9, duration=0.1100000000000001, confidence=0.925, substring=are, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c026db80>, substringRange={49, 3}, timestamp=2.01, duration=0.1699999999999999, confidence=0.925, substring=you, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c026dbc0>, substringRange={53, 7}, timestamp=2.18, duration=0.3300000000000001, confidence=0.925, substring=looking, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0271380>, substringRange={61, 3}, timestamp=2.51, duration=0.1199999999999997, confidence=0.927, substring=for, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c027bc80>, substringRange={65, 11}, timestamp=2.63, duration=0.3800000000000003, confidence=0.818349, substring=things that, alternativeSubstrings=(\n    \"things are\"\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c027bd40>, substringRange={77, 3}, timestamp=3.01, duration=0.1499999999999999, confidence=0.942, substring=you, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c027bd80>, substringRange={81, 7}, timestamp=3.16, duration=1.62, confidence=0.826, substring=alright, alternativeSubstrings=(\n    \"are right\"\n)"
), <SFTranscription: 0x1c0033860>, formattedString=Hey there what's going on with you today how are you looking for things are you are right, segments=(
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275340>, substringRange={0, 16}, timestamp=0.28, duration=0.52, confidence=0.6732572, substring=Hey there what's, alternativeSubstrings=(\n    \"Hello what's\"\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c027bd00>, substringRange={17, 5}, timestamp=0.8, duration=0.26, confidence=0.931, substring=going, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275000>, substringRange={23, 2}, timestamp=1.06, duration=0.09999999999999987, confidence=0.928, substring=on, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0270e00>, substringRange={26, 4}, timestamp=1.16, duration=0.1500000000000001, confidence=0.928, substring=with, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275dc0>, substringRange={31, 3}, timestamp=1.31, duration=0.1099999999999999, confidence=0.924, substring=you, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275040>, substringRange={35, 5}, timestamp=1.42, duration=0.3200000000000001, confidence=0.925, substring=today, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275300>, substringRange={41, 3}, timestamp=1.74, duration=0.1600000000000001, confidence=0.925, substring=how, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0275b00>, substringRange={45, 3}, timestamp=1.9, duration=0.1100000000000001, confidence=0.925, substring=are, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c026db80>, substringRange={49, 3}, timestamp=2.01, duration=0.1699999999999999, confidence=0.925, substring=you, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c026dbc0>, substringRange={53, 7}, timestamp=2.18, duration=0.3300000000000001, confidence=0.925, substring=looking, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c0271380>, substringRange={61, 3}, timestamp=2.51, duration=0.1199999999999997, confidence=0.927, substring=for, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c026d9c0>, substringRange={65, 10}, timestamp=2.63, duration=0.3800000000000003, confidence=0.818349, substring=things are, alternativeSubstrings=(\n    \"things that\"\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c026db00>, substringRange={76, 3}, timestamp=3.01, duration=0.1499999999999999, confidence=0.942, substring=you, alternativeSubstrings=(\n)",
    "<SFTranscriptionSegment: 0x1c027bdc0>, substringRange={80, 9}, timestamp=3.16, duration=1.62, confidence=0.826, substring=are right, alternativeSubstrings=(\n    alright\n)"
)]`